# Differences between the questions: "he didn't tell you? / he hasn't told you?"

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

> A= I'm so sorry Andy is moving away tomorrow.
>   B= really?
>   A= he didn't tell you /he hasn't told you?

I have seen them both used in similar contexts but I was wondering  is there a difference?

Comment: It's just the diffference between the simple past (*didn't tell*) and the present perfect (*hasn't told*).  Did you look up those two tenses?

Comment: What I know is that "didn't tell" is used when referring to an action that took place at a precise moment in the past, while "haven't told" is tied to the present , it means up to now. With that being said I have noticed that in situations where people are talking in general without mentioning any particular period of time  they use both. So I was asking about the difference if there's any.

Answer (score 1):

For differentiating between the two we need to understand when and where simple past and present perfect are used.

- 1. Past Tense.
     a. The past tense is used to talk about the past.
     b. The past tense is used to describe the present or future in a 
      conditional statement.
     c. The past tense is used to make a hypothetical statement (to imagine).
     d. *The past tense is used in a polite expression*.
- 2. Present Perfect Tense.
     a. Unspecified point in the past.
     b. An action that occurred in the past, but has a result in the present 
      (now).
     c. Talking about general experiences (ever, never).
     d. Events that recently occurred (just).
     e. Events that have occurred up to now (yet).
     f. Events that occurred before you expected (already).
     g. Events that began in the past and haven't changed (for, since).
- if Andy has moved away already past tense ( he didn't tell you ) shall be used. But A and B are talking about something which has to occur in near future and there might be possibility that Andy will tell person B about it eventually. So present perfect tense (he hasn't told you) shall be used.
  Note : I only answered what i know.

Comment: I'm going to see if I have understood. Example : My friend went to a party without telling me the day before today. Today another friend of mine comes up to me and tells me about my friend being to the party. Now my answer is "I didn't know, he didn't tell me anything about that." Could I also say "He hasn't told me anything about that" considering that maybe he hasn't had time to tell me so up to now but in the future he could?

Comment: Yes. You can. Remember, the first reply emphasize on the fact that you are cool about it. And the second reply emphasizes that you  are bit upset or questioning why he hasn't told me. get the idea?

Comment: Yes I finally get it but if in the future realizing he still hasn't told me anything I want to talk this over with him. Can I ask him :"Why haven't you told me anything about that?" or is it better to say:"Why didn't you tell me anything about that?"?

Comment: It's better to say, 'why didn't you tell me?'